# Implementing language locales into array to be used in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, locale

I'm trying to read every file in a directory, clean up with java util.locale, then write to a new directory. The reading and writing methods work, the Locale.SPANISH might be the issue as I have read in other posts.

I iterated through the available languages in the java.util.locale, spanish was in there.

First, the array issue: the following extract of code below is the long way of entering the Locale.(LANGUAGE) into the array. This seems to work fine. However, I can't understand why the 'short' way doesn't seem to work.

```
String[] languageLocale = new String[fileArray.length];

languageLocale[0] = "Locale.ENGLISH";

languageLocale[1] = "Locale.FRENCH";

languageLocale[2] = "Locale.GERMAN";

languageLocale[3] = "Locale.ITALIAN";

languageLocale[4] = "Locale.SPANISH";
```

The short way:

```
String[] languageLocale = new String[("Locale.ENGLISH" , "Locale.FRENCH" , "Locale.GERMAN" , "Locale.ITALIAN" , "Locale.SPANISH")];
```

I need to input the Locale.(langauge) into a string so they can be called in the following:

```
File file = new File("\\LanguageGuessing5.0\\Learning\\");
File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();

ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
        if (fileArray[i].isFile()) {
            if (fileArray[i].isHidden()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                String content = readUTF8File("\\LanguageGuessing5.0\\Learning\\"+fileArray[i].getName());

                words = extractWords(content, languageLocale[i]);

                outputWordsToUTF8File("\\LanguageGuessing5.0\\Model\\"+ fileArray[i].getName() + "out.txt", words);
            }
        } else if (fileArray[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + fileArray[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

The following method call:
    words = extractWords(content, languageLocale[i]);
also presents the following error:

The method extractWords(String, Locale) in the type CleaningText(the class name) is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

My understanding is that while the array argument is not a locale, the string holds the correct text to make it valid. I'm clearly incorrect, I'm hoping someone could explain how this works.

The input types of the methods are below for context:

```
public static String readUTF8File(String filePath)
public static ArrayList extractWords(String inputText, Locale currentLocale)
public static void outputWordsToUTF8File(String filePath, ArrayList wordList)
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: about the error you get, your method extractWords is expecting a Locale object and you provide a String. You can use the Locale class mapping like this: Locale.forLanguageTag(Locale.CHINESE.getLanguage()) --> mapping from String to Locale using language tag

Comment: @AdiOhana How can this be used to iterate through different languages? i need a different language for each file. I need something such like  extractWords(content, Locale.forLanguageTag(Locale.languageLocale[i].getLanguage()));

Comment: If you have the list of all languages as mentioned above,assuming it is a known list, you can iterate using Locale method as I mentioned

Comment: @AdiOhana sorry im not familiar, how would I iterate through this